# R setting color and shape according to variables

Tags: r, plot

I have a table, myTable, that looks like this:

```
x                 y    ReportType
1                 0.9      1
1                 0.87     2
1                 0.92     3
2                 0.66     1
2                 0.98     2
2                 0.83     3
3                 0.54     1
3                 0.87     2
3                 0.67     3
```

I wish to plot it so the x variable is on the x-axis and the y variable is on the y-axis.

I want the points to be a different color based on what x is (so x = 1 would be a different color than x = 2 points than x = 3 points).

Then for each point, I want it to have a different shape based on what it's ReportType is (so all points with ReportType = 1 would be different shape than ReportType = 2 points than ReportType = 3 points).

So far, I have:

```
plot(myTable$KernelFunction, myTable$Value)
```

but I'm not sure how to modify the color and shape as such.

Comment: Hi Anna! I'd recommend a ggplot2 tutorial if you want to get started with plotting. That's a really great package lots of users on SO use.

Answer (score 1):

Recreate dataframe:

```
myTable <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                     y = 1:9/10,
                     ReportType = rep(c(1,2,3),times = 3))
```

Base R:

```
plot(x = myTable$x, y = myTable$y, col = myTable$x, pch = myTable$ReportType)
```

[image]

ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(myTable,aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
geom_point(aes(col = factor(x), shape = factor(ReportType))) + 
theme_bw()
```

[image]